# Does Google Update perform cryptographic checks against releases?

Tags: digital-signature, attack-prevention, google, software, attack-vector

My company is looking to allow Google Chrome to self-update, a necessity as we are finding it difficult to keep up with their release cycle in order to mitigate vulnerabilities.

On the pro side, letting the software auto-update helps us reduce the prevalence published Chrome vulnerabilities.

On the negative side, this introduces the risk of a supply-chain attack. However, given the sheer number of Chrome (as well as other browsers) vulnerabilities and the experience Google has with vulnerability research / bugbounty programs, I believe the auto-update route provides significant risk reduction.

The question I am looking for help in answering is surrounding the Google Update service (specifically on a Windows 10+ workstation) and how it verifies the update package it receives? I have searched up and down and am unable to find any information on it. Project Omaha (https://github.com/google/omaha) appears to be an unofficial analog to Google Update (perhaps an earlier fork?) but I'm also not finding anything in there.

I'm specifically interested in knowing if the Google Update service, at a minimum, checks the digital signature of the package. That would at least alleviate the risk of a BGP hijack attack vector.

Appreciate any help!